# Ansible <type 'list'> cannot be converted to a dict?

Tags: ansible

I have written a playbook to upgrade my OS from 14.04 to 16.04 and i am getting a lot of interactive prompts.

Here is an example of a prompt :-

[image]

Here is my ansible playbook so far :-

```
- hosts: os-updates
  gather_facts: yes
  become: yes

  tasks:
    - name: Current Distribution
      debug: msg="{{ ansible_distribution }}"

    - name: Current Distribution version
      debug: msg="{{ ansible_distribution_version}}"

    - name: Comment out old Docker Repo
      command: sed -i '1 s/^/#/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/apt_dockerproject_org_repo.list

    # Start the update from current os to next OS
    - name: Update apt get repo
      apt: update_cache=yes force_apt_get=yes cache_valid_time=3600
      when: 
        - ansible_os_family == "Debian"
        - ansible_distribution_version != "20.04"

    - name: Upgrade all apt packages
      expect:
        command: sudo apt-get upgrade -y
        responses:
          - "A new version of /boot/grub/menu.lst is available, but the version installed currently has been locally modified. What would you like to do about menu.lst?": "keep the local version currently installed"
          - "A new version of /boot/grub/menu.lst is available, but the version installed currently has been locally modified. What would you like to do about menu.lst?": "keep the local version currently installed"

    - name: Success test
      debug:
        msg: "{{ }}"
```

But i keep running into the following error message :-

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "argument responses is of type <type 'list'> and we were unable to convert to dict: <type 'list'> cannot be converted to a dict"}
```

What am i doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried the using `apt` module itself? There is an example which shows how to `Upgrade all packages` (or `dist-upgrade`).

Comment: `What am i doing wrong?` <= As documented on the module page and as clearly reported by your error message, you are passing a list in `responses` where it is expecting a dict.

Comment: The `expect` module, either requires a list of answers or a dictionary of `key => question`; `value => answer`, not a list of dictionary, as you are providing it at the moment.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Awesome. I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have used to upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 to 20.04

4 files - 2 tasks, 1 handler and a playbook.

os-upgrade-ubuntu.tsk

reboot-if-needed.tsk

reboot-if-needed.hnd

playbook.yml

**os-upgrade-ubuntu.tsk**

```
# Use a block to perform tasks conditionally—only if running Ubuntu 
#- debug:  msg="os-upgrade-ubuntu.tsk  {{oldos}} ... {{newos}}"
  - debug:  msg="os-upgrade-ubuntu.tsk ... checking for OS Upgrade current version {{ansible_distribution_version}}"

  - name: regather facts to get the latest information 
    setup:

  - name: Verify DNS resolution
    raw:  (echo "nameserver 1.1.1.1" | resolvconf  -d any  && echo "nameserver 1.1.1.1" | resolvconf -a any)
    #ignore_errors: true

  - block:
    - name: OS Upgrade ... Remove the EOL message of the day if one exists.
      file:
        path: "{{ item }}"
        state: absent
      with_items:
        - /etc/update-motd.d/99-esm
        - /run/motd.dynamic

    - name: OS Upgrade ... Upgrade all packages to the latest version
      apt: update_cache=yes upgrade=full

    - name: OS Upgrade ... Ensure update-manager-core is installed.
      apt: name=update-manager-core state=present

    - import_tasks: reboot-if-needed.tsk

    - name: OS Upgrade ... Run do-release-upgrade non-interactively.
      command: do-release-upgrade -f DistUpgradeViewNonInteractive

    - name: regather facts to get the latest information 
      setup:

    when: ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu' 
    #when: ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu' and ansible_distribution_version == {{oldos}}

# After the playbook is finished, it's a good idea to confirm all the servers
# are actually upgraded. Run something like:
#     ansible [group] -a "lsb_release -a"
```

**reboot-if-needed.tsk**

```
 - name: check if a reboot is required
    shell: "[ -f /var/run/reboot-required ]"
    failed_when: false
    register: reboot_required
    changed_when: reboot_required.rc == 0
    notify: 
      - reboot
      - wait_for_ready

# make handlers run ... now and not at end of play
  - name: flush handlers
    meta: flush_handlers
```

**reboot-if-needed.hnd**

```
 - name: reboot
    reboot:
      reboot_timeout: 1200
      test_command: mount

  - name: wait_for_ready
    wait_for:
      host: "{{ ansible_ssh_host }}"
      port: 22
      state: started
    connection: local
    become: no
```

**playbook.yml**

```
---
- name: Update OS and apply patches
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  handlers:
    - include: reboot-if-needed.hnd
  tass:

  # If system requires a reboot, then reboot
  - import_tasks: reboot-if-needed.tsk

  - name: Install Aptitude if needed
    raw: test -e /usr/bin/aptitude || (apt -y update && apt install -y aptitude)

  - name: Verify DNS resolution
    raw:  (echo "nameserver 1.1.1.1" | resolvconf  -d any  && echo "nameserver 1.1.1.1" | resolvconf -a any)
    #ignore_errors: true

  - name: Update apt cache
    apt:
      update_cache: yes
      cache_valid_time: 3600

  - name: Upgrade all packages to the latest version
    apt:
      name: "*"
      state: latest
  - name: Remove dependencies that are no longer required
    apt:
      autoremove: yes

  - import_tasks: reboot-if-needed.tsk

  - block:
    - set_fact:
        oldos: 16.04
        newos: 18.04
    - import_tasks: reboot-if-needed.tsk
    - import_tasks: os-upgrade-ubuntu.tsk
    - import_tasks: reboot-if-needed.tsk
    when: ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu' and ansible_distribution_version == '16.04'

  - block:
    - set_fact:
        oldos: 18.04
        newos: 20.04
    - import_tasks: reboot-if-needed.tsk
    - import_tasks: os-upgrade-ubuntu.tsk
    - import_tasks: reboot-if-needed.tsk
    when: ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu' and ansible_distribution_version == '18.04'


  # if running Ubuntu 20.04 - no upgrade to be done
  - block:
    - debug:
        msg: 'This server is running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ... no upgrade will be performed.'
    when: ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu' and ansible_distribution_version == '20.04'
  - import_tasks: reboot-if-needed.tsk
```